# Gutenberg translation is not working

Tags: block-editor

I have followed the documentation of WordPress on translating Gutenberg block, I have used WP CLI to create the .pot, .po and .json file and uploaded to my langauges folder inside the folder of that plugin, but still it is not working. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

PHP:

```
function custom_blocks_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'custom-blocks', FALSE, '');
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'custom_blocks_load_plugin_textdomain' );

//register block template
function block_registration_template($block_path, $block_handle, $script_handle, $render_callback = false){
    wp_register_script(
        $script_handle,
        plugins_url( $block_path , __FILE__ ),
        [ 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-editor' ],
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( $block_path , __FILE__ ) )
    );

    $parameters = array(
        'editor_script' => $script_handle,
    );

    if($render_callback){
        $parameters['render_callback'] = $render_callback;
    }

    register_block_type( $block_handle, $parameters );

}

function block_registration(){
block_registration_template('/ref_block.js', 'custom-blocks/ref', 'CUSTOM-block-ref');

block_registration_template('/ref_holder_block.js', 'custom-blocks/ref-holder', 'CUSTOM-block-ref-holder');
}

add_action('init', 'block_registration');

function custom_blocks_set_script_translations() {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'CUSTOM-block-ref-holder', 'custom-blocks');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blocks_set_script_translations' );
```

JS

```
(() => {
    const __ = wp.i18n.__; // The __() for internationalization.
    const el = wp.element.createElement; // The wp.element.createElement() function to create elements.
    const registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType; // The registerBlockType() to register blocks.

    const ServerSideRender = wp.components.ServerSideRender;
    const TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;
    const TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl;
    const InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
    const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor;
    const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;

    //Custom variable
    const allowedBlocks = [ 'custom-blocks/ref' ] ;
    const blockTemplate = [ [ 'custom-blocks/ref', {} ] ];

    registerBlockType( 'custom-blocks/ref-holder', { // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        title: __( 'Reference Holder', 'custom-blocks' ), // Block title.

        category: 'custom_block',
        keywords: [ __('ref'), 'custom-blocks'],
        attributes: {

        },
        supports: {
            customClassName: false,
            className: false,
        },

        edit(props) {

            return el(
                'div', { className: 'ref-block-holder'},
                el('h2', {}, __('Reference', 'custom-blocks') ), 
                el ( InnerBlocks,
                {
                    allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                    template: blockTemplate
                } )
            );
        },

        save(props) {

            return el(
                'div', { className: 'ref-block-holder'},
                el('h2', {}, __('Reference', 'custom-blocks') ),
                el ( InnerBlocks.Content,
                {
                    allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                    template: blockTemplate
                } )
            );
        },
    });
})();
```

JSON:

```
{ 
   "translation-revision-date":"2020-02-10 15:33+0800",
   "generator":"WP-CLI/2.4.0",
   "source":"ref_holder_block.js",
   "domain":"custom-blocks",
   "locale_data":{ 
      "messages":{ 
         "":{ 
            "domain":"custom-blocks",
            "lang":"zh_HK",
            "plural-forms":"nplurals=1; plural=0;"
         },
         "Reference":[ 
            "\u53c3\u8003\u8cc7\u6599"
         ],
         "Reference Holder":[ 
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer for myself.  If you want to make the translation works, you have to register the script with `wp_register_script()` in `init` action hook and enqueue scripts in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, if you hook `wp_set_script_translations` to `init`.

If you run `wp_register_script()` `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and hook `wp_set_script_translations` to `init`, `wp_set_script_translations` would not be able to get the handle because `init` fires first!

Finally!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent all day debugging this issue, and by looking at the code I can guess we shared the same problems:

1. assuming `$script_handle` is `CUSTOM-block-ref-holder`, the PHP file is *almost* correct.
2. `wp_set_script_translations` needs the full path to work. In your case, although you probably need to adjust for your path, it should be something like

```php
wp_set_script_translations(
  'CUSTOM-block-ref-holder',
  'custom-blocks',
  plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'languages/'
);
```

3. The name of the JSON file should be `custom-blocks-zh_HK-CUSTOM-block-ref-holder.json`
4. The "domain" fields don't really matter in the JSON (as of today), I left them as `messages`, as per default from WP CLI, but in my tests they worked even with totally arbitrary and random strings.

Reference: [JavaScript i18n support in WordPress 5 | Advanced usage](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/)