# Issue with translation - Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, translation, localization

Here is my code.

I based it on CapitaineWP formation and template.
I have the .pot, .po, .mo and .json files.

$script_asset_path = PERSO_FOLDER."/build/index.asset.php";

if ( ! file_exists( $script_asset_path ) ) {
throw new \Error(
'You need to run `npm start` or `npm run build` for the "create-block/perso-chacha-bases" block first. ('.$script_asset_path.')'
);
}

```
$index_js     = '/build/index.js';
$script_asset = require( $script_asset_path );
wp_register_script(
    'perso-chacha-bases-block-editor',
    PERSO_URL.$index_js,
    $script_asset['dependencies'],
    $script_asset['version']
);
wp_set_script_translations(
    'perso-chacha-bases-block-editor',
    'perso-chacha',
    PERSO_FOLDER . '/languages'
);

$editor_css = '/build/index.css';
wp_register_style(
    'perso-chacha-bases-block-editor',
    PERSO_URL.$editor_css,
    array(),
    filemtime( PERSO_FOLDER.$editor_css )
);

$style_css = '/build/style-index.css';
wp_register_style(
    'perso-chacha-bases-block',
    PERSO_URL.$style_css,
    array(),
    filemtime( PERSO_FOLDER.$style_css )
);

register_block_type( 'create-block/perso-chacha-bases', array(
    'editor_script' => 'perso-chacha-bases-block-editor',
    'editor_style'  => 'perso-chacha-bases-block-editor',
    'style'         => 'perso-chacha-bases-block',
) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I needed to add -perso-chacha-bases-block-editor after fr_FR in the json filename.
I found out this solution here: [Gutenberg translation is not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358347/gutenberg-translation-is-not-working/360646#360646)

Big thank you!